# Computing Vector times Matrix exponential

Tags: matrices, matrix-exponential

In many applications, it is not the matrix exponential $\mathrm{e}^A$ what is  needed, but rather its action on some vector $B$, so there is literature dealing with the direct computation of the action of the matrix exponential:
$$\mathrm{e}^A\times B,$$
that avoid the space and time complexities of storing and computing the full exponential. See for instance [1].

Are there similar methods for calculating the *left action* (for lack of a better name) of the exponential on a vector $B$:
$$B\times \mathrm{e}^A?$$

[1]  *Al-Mohy, Awad H.; Higham, Nicholas J.*, [**Computing the action of the matrix exponential, with an application to exponential integrators**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/100788860), SIAM J. Sci. Comput. 33, No. 2, 488-511 (2011). [ZBL1234.65028](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1234.65028). [1].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use the fact that$$(B\times e^A)^T=(e^A)^T\times B^T=e^{A^T}\times B^T.$$

Comment: I knew there had to be some trick along these lines. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @A.Arredondo I'm glad I could help.